# What is the distribution of an outer product of random values mod P?

Tags: random-variable, matrix, randomness, independence

I haven't been able to answer this daunting question for days now and I am not able to find the right resource for it, so maybe someone here might help me out.

Consider an outer product of two **uniform** random vectors **mod p**, where the vector consists of independent uniform random values modulo a prime number $p$. Vectors $A$ and $B$ are independent of each other.

$$ \begin{pmatrix} a_0 & a_1 & a_2 &.. &a_n\end{pmatrix} \mod p$$ and $$ \begin{pmatrix} b_0 & b_1 & b_2 &.. &b_n\end{pmatrix} \mod p$$

such that the outer product is

$$ \begin{pmatrix} a_0b_0 & a_1b_0 & a_2b_0 &...\\a_0b_1 & a_1b_1 & a_2b_1 &...\\a_0b_2 & a_1b_2 & a_2b_2 &...\\... &... &... &...\end{pmatrix} \mod p$$

What is the distribution of this outer product? Are the values uniform or not and are they dependent or not? Can we also get it to be uniform and independent (w.h.p) by using some other distribution for the random vectors or maybe by adding up more (k) random outer products?

Comment: Same as:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/572162/what-is-the-distribution-of-an-outer-product-of-uniform-random-vectors

Comment: Could you please explain what a "uniform random vector mod p" is?  Are the coefficients integers and $p$ a prime, or are the coefficients real numbers and $p$ any real number, or something else?  Also, please delete either this post or your cross-post on math right away so we don't have to have two parallel conversations and two sets of answers.

Comment: Are the $a$ and $b$ vectors independent of each other? Are the components independent within each vector? When you say 'uniform/dependent' do you mean "uniform *and* dependent" or "uniform *or* dependent" or "either uniform or dependent *but not both*", or something else?

Comment: Hey guys, I followed your suggestions in modifying the problem statement to be clear. I also removed the other post, sorry for that. Any suggestions would be much appreciated :)

Comment: It is unclear what you might mean by a "uniform and independent" outer product. Note that the numbers $\{0,1,\ldots,p-1\}$ modulo $p$ comprise two parts: $0$ and the rest, which form a cyclic group under multiplication. If $a$ and $b$ independently have uniform distributions over these numbers, then the chance that $ab=0$ therefore is $1/p+1/p-1/p^2=(2p-1)/p^2$ and, from the group property, the chance that $ab=c\ne 0$ is the same for all $c\ne 0$ and therefore equals $(p-1)/p^2\lt (2p-1)/p^2$. Looking for uniformity here--even in the simplest case $n=1$--is therefore hopeless.

Comment: If you relax the uniformity requirement on $a$ and $b$, then selecting $0$ with probability $1 - \sqrt{1-1/p}$ and all other values with equal probabilities does the trick: the components of the outer product are uniform. But they cannot possibly be independent, which should be evident from the fact that $a_ib_j$ and $a_{i'}b_{j'}$ have a common factor when $i=i'$ or $j=j'$. Given these facts, is there some version of this question can can be rescued and made answerable?

Comment: Nice remark, you are right. I actually need not the zero. Can we modify the distribution of both vectors A and B (by excluding zero) so as to have the outer product uniform? Also, can I have the values independent of each other by doing something additional but still have the structure of an outer product? Maybe by adding several outer products and the resulting matrix would have independent values? Thanks again & sorry for being a noobie :D

Comment: My intuition is as follows: a completely random matrix, with very high probability is non-singular and thus has rank n. And any matrix with rank k can be structured as a sum of k outer products. So I think I can get independence between the values of the matrix through a sum of k outer products that are constructed as you defined. So what is the minimum k to achieve this, probably there is an equation that defines the rate of independence with every additional outer product added. Or I might be totally wrong!

Comment: Your intuition is pretty good.  Because the rank of a sum of $k$ independent outer products can never exceed $k$, you will need to add at least $n+1$ of them.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, but I really need to have k<<n. Maybe then I can relax the requirement of complete independence and have it slightly dependent. But this first needs me to quantify the rate of independence with each additional outer product! any suggestions?

Comment: It looks like your question has evolved (which is a good thing!).  But I think it's time for you to make major edits to this question to incorporate all the additional information in these comments and state your new question.